# Oracle APEX - modifying session state of items that are database columns

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a DML Form where most of the fields are database columns. One of those fields - User, is optional in the database and is a display only item on the page. There is also a switch control on the page and when it is set to Yes, the P4_USER item gets populated with the current user name, and when it is gets switched to No, the field supposed to be cleared.

I set the dynamic action on change of the switch control to set the value of P4_USER item and to show or hide it as appropriate and it works fine. But when I submit the form I get an error:

`Session state protection violation: This may be caused by manual alteration of protected page item P4_USER. If you are unsure what caused this error, please contact the application administrator for assistance.`

I wanted to set the `Value Protected` attribute to `No` but that attribute is only there for hidden fields, mine is `Display Only`. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item is protected if the "Send On Page Submit" option is checked

[image]

but you want to send the item data, I recommend using two items one as a display only to show the data and the other as a hidden item to send the data

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Session State Protection attribute for the item to "Unrestricted".  This is under "Security" in the item attributes.